# How to have detachable tool windows in Qt

Tags: qt, qdockwidget

I am developing a tool which will have some variable sized windows. I am able to achieve this using the `QSplitter` horizontal & vertical. Please see attached image.

Now, how to make these individual windows detachable/maximize/close? How can I add cross markers at the top-right-corner of each window so that they can be closed maximized or detached from there? Just like this link :--

http://vector.com/portal/medien/ecu_testing/tae/test_automation_editor.png

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're looking for the [`QDockWidget`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qdockwidget.html) class:

> The QDockWidget class provides a widget that can be docked inside a
>   QMainWindow or floated as a top-level window on the desktop.
>   QDockWidget provides the concept of dock widgets, also know as tool
>   palettes or utility windows. Dock windows are secondary windows placed
>   in the dock widget area around the central widget in a QMainWindow.

Check out [this example](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-mainwindows-dockwidgets-example.html)

Comment: thanks .. is it possible to do this with QT creator.. actually i am not able to -- combine qdockwidget in the lay out as shown in my attached picture using qt creator ?

Comment: You can create each child window as a `QDockWidget` using the designer. But I think you'll need code to add them to the main window. To create a `QDockWindow`: *File > New > Qt > Qt Designer From Class > Widgets/QDockWidget*. Then in `MainWindow` constructor: `MyDockWidget* dock = new MyDockWidget(this); addDockWidget(Qt::RightDockWidgetArea, dock);` as in the example.

Comment: got the point i will try this... last one ... do we have to specify the default position for each window ?

Comment: I think so yes. When you call `addDockWidget`, you need to pass the area. And before you ask your next question, you can dock your `QDockWidget` derived widget programmatically with `dock->setFloating(false);` :)

Answer (score 0):

In 2021, there is [KDQDockWidget](https://www.kdab.com/development-resources/qt-tools/kddockwidgets/?gclid=CjwKCAjwqcKFBhAhEiwAfEr7zYRfOQgPLNfDXtDXg3CcdBROj_-YbZomqZl1Ky0GQsQPKgeyVCcUzhoCq64QAvD_BwE#sublist), an apparently much better Qt docking framework with both commercial and open source licenses.

The site lists the following advantages:

- It provides advanced docking that QDockWidgets doesn’t support.
- The layouting engine honors min/max size constraints and some size policies.
- Supports PySide2 bindings.
- Clean codebase.
- Supports lazy separator resize.
- You can reorder tabs with the mouse.
- Supports partial layout save/restore, affecting only a chosen sub-set.
- Allows double clicking on title bar to maximize.
- Allows double clicking on separator to distribute equally.
- Shows close button on tabs.
- Allows you to make a dock widget non-closable and/or non-dockable.
- Provides an optional maximize button on the title bar.
- FloatingWindows can be utility windows or full native.